# How to handle AJAX when PHP code fails but sends 200?

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling

I have an application that uses JavaScript on the frontend and communicates with PHP on the backend using AJAX.

If the code encounters an error that I accounted for, **I make sure to set the HTTP status code to something other than 200 and I handle it appropriately** in the JavaScript, cleanly displaying to the user that an error occurred.

However, if an unexpected error comes up or something somewhere went horribly wrong for some reason, the PHP code will still return 200 and will echo the error instead of the desired output. An easy example of this occurring would be if there was a syntax error in the PHP code (*obviously the code should always be thoroughly tested before pushing it to production so a user should never encounter a PHP syntax error, but let us just use this as an example of errors that generate similar responses from the server.*)

[image: An example of an error]
I'm logging the error to give an example of what I mean, but usually this PHP parse error responseText wouldn't be logging to the console, only the red Chrome error would appear.

Is there a way to capture these errors that browsers log and respond cleanly to the user, instead of just having everything break and be left in a half-loaded state? What is the best ways to respond to errors which occur in the PHP code but that still send a default 200 response back?

---

### A potential solution?

A tentative idea that I came up with as I was writing this question is to have the very first line of every PHP script set the status code to 500, and then if I encounter an expected error set the status code to the appropriate error code and only on the line before I successfully echo out the script's results set the status code back to 200. This works in most cases, but it seems like more of a workaround or a hack to me... Is this an appropriate way to cover for all completely unexpected errors? What is standard in the industry?

Comment: Use `try/catch` in the code that processes the response.

Comment: I did a **lot** of research on Stack Overflow and other sites before posting this question and was not able to find a solution so if there is something I am overlooking, please note that it was not out of laziness or derision at all! Let me know if there is a way I can improve my question before downvoting because I will be happy to!

Comment: @Barmar try-catch in the Javascript code, checking if the content returned is in the format expected, you mean?

Comment: @Guy I interpreted it to mean in the PHP. Put the whole PHP script in a try catch so that you can set the response code to 500 if there's an exception

Comment: I meant it in the JS, to catch the error when trying to parse the JSON that's supposed to be returned.

Comment: @ControlAltDel The problem is that there isn't an exception, it's reporting a syntax error.

Comment: You can't solve this with code in the PHP script, because syntax errors are detected before executing the code.

Comment: You should never send exception/syntax errors to the frontend. Make sure your server is configured to do this. Regardless - if your output is not json - you can't json-parse it. So even if your server returns 500 with empty content (because you made sure to not send syntax errors) - you frontend should know not to try and parse it, or another option - try/catch the parse part.

Comment: @Dekel The problem is that the server isn't sending 500 if there is a syntax error, because the default status code is 200. (Unless I use the potential solution I mentioned in the question, but is that the correct way of doing things?)

Comment: No, I think not. You should configure the server to set the correct status code on syntax error, and not send the errors to the client. Which server are you using?

Comment: What about unexpected errors that aren't necessarily a syntax error, though, but were somehow overlooked are unaccounted for in the PHP code?

Comment: Not the database server. The web server. It is the one that sends back the syntax-error to the frontend.

Comment: Oh, duh, that was a mistake, I wasn't thinking. The server I am using is an Apache web server. I am using a WAMP stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I make sure to set the HTTP status code to something other than 200 and I handle it appropriately

That's good.

> the PHP code will still return 200 and will echo the error

Then your PHP is misconfigured. A production web application should never, EVER be allowed to write default error messages to the end user. That is a problem with your PHP configuration and is only set in the configuration (although it can be overridden in code).

Assuming that you have to run a code base you can't control, then the most obvious solution I can think of is to use an auto-prepend script (i.e. does not depend on explicitly modifying each entry script) to set a custom error handler. In your good code, always set the error response somewhere that the handler can read it (a global variable would be a candidate) before you execute something which might go awry.

Comment: I was encountering this in a test server on my own computer so I do have access to the server configurations. I didn't realize there is a setting in the configurations to send a fail code on syntax error. The production code base for the company I am working for probably has this setting configured correctly, I assume.

Comment: There isn't a way of forcing a status code via configuration - but the status code and the content are 2 seperate things, both of which you want to address in your solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, @Dekel's second comment on the question made it seem as if there is a way to force status code via the configuration. Assuming that errors are being logged away to some internal file and not echoed to the user, on a syntax error the server would still send a 200 status code and a blank content response, correct? How should I handle getting the blank content response with a 200 status code?

Comment: experimentation, output buffering and/or javascript handling for a null response. Although it is unusual to have a fatal error which only manfists sometimes at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

By my experience with php try to pass the response on php with a json encode and on js use jsondecode! echo json_encode($response);